# need help to slice the words in python

Tags: python, network-programming

Need help to find the string **NAME: "3640 chassis"** and **SN: FF1045C5** from below output

term len 0

R1#sh inventory

NAME: "3640 chassis", DESCR: "3640 chassis"

PID:                   , VID: 0xFF, SN: FF1045C5

NAME: "One port Fastethernet TX", DESCR: "One port Fastethernet TX"

PID: NM-1FE-TX=        , VID: 1.0, SN: 7720321

NAME: "One port Fastethernet TX", DESCR: "One port Fastethernet TX"

PID: NM-1FE-TX=        , VID: 1.0, SN: 7720321

NAME: "One port Fastethernet TX", DESCR: "One port Fastethernet TX"

PID: NM-1FE-TX=        , VID: 1.0, SN: 7720321

NAME: "One port Fastethernet TX", DESCR: "One port Fastethernet TX"

PID: NM-1FE-TX=        , VID: 1.0, SN: 7720321

R1#

Regards
Devraj

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: Please edit your question as it is ***too unclear*** at the moment with regards to what you're trying to ask

Comment: I tried below to get teh desired output but no luck.

input_data = open('abc.txt') 
out = input_data.find('NAME:')
print out
output = input_data.find('SN:')
print output
print input_data[out:].strip("\t\n\r\n")
print input_data[output:].strip("\t\n\r\n")

Answer (score 0):

So, this was the input file **test.txt**:

```
term len 0

R1#sh inventory

NAME: "3640 chassis", DESCR: "3640 chassis" 
PID: , VID: 0xFF, SN: FF1045C5

NAME: "One port Fastethernet TX", DESCR: "One port Fastethernet TX" 
PID: NM-1FE-TX= , VID: 1.0, SN: 7720321

NAME: "One port Fastethernet TX", DESCR: "One port Fastethernet TX" 
PID: NM-1FE-TX= , VID: 1.0, SN: 7720321

NAME: "One port Fastethernet TX", DESCR: "One port Fastethernet TX" 
PID: NM-1FE-TX= , VID: 1.0, SN: 7720321

NAME: "One port Fastethernet TX", DESCR: "One port Fastethernet TX" 
PID: NM-1FE-TX= , VID: 1.0, SN: 7720321

R1#
```

and this might help:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for eachLine in f:
        if 'NAME: "3640 chassis"' in eachLine or 'SN: FF1045C5' in eachLine:                
            print "match found in line: ", eachLine
```

and output will be like:

```
match found in line:  NAME: "3640 chassis", DESCR: "3640 chassis" 
match found in line:  PID: , VID: 0xFF, SN: FF1045C5
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply tkhurana. But with the given script i am getting nothing as 'NAME: "3640 chassis"' and 'SN: FF1045C5' are in different line.

Comment: @Devraj updated my answer according to the condition that 'NAME: "3640 chassis"' and 'SN: FF1045C5' are in different line

Comment: Thank you tkhuran.  Your code help me to identify desired output.

Comment: @Devraj glad it helped you,  Don't hesitate to accept my answer if you found it useful :)